# Why at night the light of all stars get in small amount to earth?

Tags: star, light

What i mean, why we still get dark if all the stars are sending their light to earth.

Comment: Please look up Olbers paradox.

Comment: Strongly linked https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13742/why-when-we-look-through-a-telescope-in-space-do-the-billions-of-stars-not-bloc?rq=1 if not a duplicate.

Comment: Please clarify your confusion.  It's not obvious whether you're headed for Olber's paradox or simply that you don't know how light propogates from a distant point source.